# sed insert line with leading spaces to a specific line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a line with spaces in the start for example " Hello world".
I want to insert this line to a specific line in a file.
For example
insert "   hello world" to the next file

```
hello
world
```

result:

```
hello
    hello world
world
```

I am using this sed script:

```
sed -i "${line} i ${text}" $file
```

the problem is that I am getting my new line without the spaces:

```
hello
hello world
world
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can escape the `space` character, for example to add 2 spaces:

```
sed -i "${line} i \ \ ${text}" $file
```

Or you can do it in the definition of your `text` variable:

```
text="\ \ hello world"
```

Comment: You only to escape the first space. Sed seem to automatically recognize the rest of the spaces. E.g., `a\    text` appends the text with 4 spaces at the front.

Comment: i spent sometime in searching a escape character for whitespace, then i saw this, was like why didnt i think of this... Thanks

Answer (score 56):

You only need one `\` to input multiple blanks
like this

```
sed -i "${line} i \    ${text}" $file
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ a="  some string  "
$ echo -e "hello\nworld"
hello
world
$ echo -e "hello\nworld" | sed "/world/ s/.*/${a}.\n&/" 
hello
  some string  .
world
```

The `.` was added in the substitution above to demonstrate that the trailing whitepsaces are preserved.  Use `sed "/world/ s/.*/${a}\n&/"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by splitting the expression like this:

```sh
sed -i $file -e '2i\' -e "     $text"
```

This is a GNU extension for easier scripting.