# Inserting strings with spaces with sed

Tags: bash, loops, sed, insert, whitespace

I've seen this asked a fair bit on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find a solution that will fit me.

**The problem**
I have a for loop generate a list of ipaddresses and names for each ipaddress, based on what the user inputs. So the user is asked "What would you like to call the series, what is the number of the first ipaddress and how many are there?".

So if a user puts in slave, 12 (0 is appended onto the end making the first 120 in this case), and then 3. I then want sed to put this list into /etc/hosts.

**What I have tried**
I was using perl and I tried using a perl one liner from before to insert (I had used it with an XML doc before) but it did not work. I tried sed and (I think) the white spaces between each ipaddress and name is throwing it off. I tried googling around but the solutions I have tried did not work. Either I messed up when writing my code or I have a special case. Unfortunately for me, I think it;s a case of the former rather than the latter! but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong so!

**The Code**

```
printf "\nMake sure you have ran part 1 of this installation script\nThis is    the script for a single node instance\n"

function begin () {

   getmasterip

}

function getmasterip () {
   #printf "\nNow getting ipaddress of master node\n"
   ip="$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')"
   echo $ip

   read -p "Enter slave series name: " series
   read -p "Enter number of slaves: " number
   read -p "Enter ip address of first slave (192.168.160.XX0): " ipadd

   #echo "192.168.160.${ipadd}0 is the first slave, will create series now"

   arr=""
   #arr=('${ip} hdmaster')
   sn="$number"
   #for ((i=0; i<sn; ++i )); do
      #arr+="192.168.160.${ipadd}${i} ${series}${i}\n"
   #done
   insert=$(for ((i=0; i<sn; ++i)); do
               printf "192.168.160.${ipadd}${i} ${series}${i}"
            done )

   printf "\nNow adding ipaddress to /etc/hosts storing in output for test\n"
   #sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak
   #perl -ne 'print $_;print "\n'${ip}' hdmaster\n" if(/ubuntu/);'  /etc/hosts > /etc/hosts

   find="ubuntu"
   line="${ip} hadmaster\n ${arr}"
   #sed -i "${line} i \ \ ${text}" /etc/hosts
   echo "line to find --- " ${find}
   echo "text to insert --- " ${insert}
   echo "hdmaster --- " ${ip}
   sed -i '/ubuntu/a ${insert} ' /etc/hosts
}

function cases () {
   read -p "WARNING: This script is intended to be RUN AS SUDO and as part 2, would you like to continue? (y/n): " choice
   case $choice in
      y)
         begin;;
      n)
         echo "Terminating program"
         exit 1;;
      *)
         echo "Use either y (yes) or n (no)"
         cases;;
   esac
}

cases
```

I had much more commented out code but I only removed the ones I was absolutely sure were on the complete wrong track. I saw this post on the site ( [sed insert line with spaces to a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439528/sed-insert-line-with-spaces-to-a-specific-line) ) and thought I could store the entire lot in a string with new lines coded in. The white spaces still mess with the insert thogh (well I think thats the issue)

**More information**
I want to improve me bash scripting and overall Linux skills so I thought I'd create an install script for a Hadoop cluster on VMs as a way of practising.

**TL:DR**
I'm trying to insert a bunch of strings with sed (that are generated by a for loop). How can I do so, as I can't seem to grasp sed.

Thank you, :)
Bosca

**EDIT**
Sorry I left out the error code I'm getting!

```
sed: can't read slave0192.168.160.121: No such file or directory
sed: can't read slave1192.168.160.122: No such file or directory
sed: can't read slave2 : No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the specfic command in this that isn't working ? Also `${insert}` is in single quotes and so won't expand.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting! Sorry thats an old thing I was trying before posting. When I have it without quotes it says: 

sed: can't read slave0192.168.160.121: No such file or directory
sed: can't read slave1192.168.160.122: No such file or directory
sed: can't read slave2 : No such file or directory

Comment: If youdon't mind my asking, why is it sometimes I have to put '${X}', $X or ${X}. I looked it up but it seems to change with each command that is used!

Comment: Update the code in your question to reflect the current state then, double quoting it would remove that error but would probably still fail for other reasons. Sed is pretty awful for appending data. I would recommend using awk instead and passing in the variable.

Comment: As for your other question look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my code. I'm going to take a peek at that link and give awk a shot.

Comment: So I tried using awk (following this guide also - http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/insert-line-before-or-after-pattern.html point #5).

I understand it's generally condition {do} but I'm not sure why it's not working. I'm getting eros stating:

`awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ;`

but my syntax looks correct? `awk '/ubuntu/{print;print ${line};next}1'` /etc/hosts

Is it an issue with my `${line}` or `${arr}` variables? `${line}` is `"${ip} hadmaster\n ${arr}"` and `${arr}` is the result of a for loop. `${ip}` is just an ipaddress.

Comment: Look up how to pass variables to awk and it may help you, also $`something` reperesents a field in awk not a variable. If you are still struggling open a new question